fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output in gitlab pipeline

The GitLab project job is not properly initialized.
I also tried using GIT_DEPTH, but the same issue appeared in the pipeline. I copied the project to a new repository and ran the GitLab pipeline, but the issue persisted.
How to fix this invalid index-pack issue in GitLab pipeline?
